# Matrix chat gets freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.4

I'm using VECTOR 0.6.17 and when I run my app in XCode 9.4, the app is running and chat is getting logged in correctly and the user's to whom I chatted previously is showing. When I click a particular user the app freezes and I can't do anything after that. I have attached the log.

```
2018-09-11 11:31:03.959131+0530 Vector[317:22327] [MXKRoomDataSource] paginateToFillRect: {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}

2018-09-11 11:31:03.959224+0530 Vector[317:22327] [MXKRoomDataSource] paginateToFillRect: Prefill with data from the store

2018-09-11 11:31:03.959321+0530 Vector[317:22327] [MXEventTimeline] paginate 30 messages in !eCuIjpMTkujUAaerDm:matrix.org (10 are retrieved from the store)

2018-09-11 11:31:03.960371+0530 Vector[317:22327] [MXEventTimeline] paginate : is done from the store

=================================================================

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:]

PID: 317, TID: 22759, Thread name: (none), Queue name: MXKRoomDataSource, QoS: 0

Backtrace:

4   Vector                              0x0000000101216a6c +[AvatarGenerator imageFromText:withBackgroundColor:] + 480

5   Vector                              0x0000000101217060 +[AvatarGenerator avatarForText:andColorIndex:] + 448

6   Vector                              0x0000000101217268 +[AvatarGenerator generateAvatarForMatrixItem:withDisplayName:] + 188

7   Vector                              0x000000010123c8d8 -[RoomBubbleCellData initWithEvent:andRoomState:andRoomDataSource:] + 348

8   Vector                              0x0000000101471548 __41-[MXKRoomDataSource processQueuedEvents:]_block_invoke + 2092

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001023591dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235919c _dispatch_client_callout + 16

11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102367dfc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 768

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235c6ac _dispatch_queue_invoke + 328

13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102368d54 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 352

14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236fe38 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 676

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478bb08 start_wqthread + 4

2018-09-11 11:31:03.981613+0530 Vector[317:22759] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:]

PID: 317, TID: 22759, Thread name: (none), Queue name: MXKRoomDataSource, QoS: 0

Backtrace:

4   Vector                              0x0000000101216a6c +[AvatarGenerator imageFromText:withBackgroundColor:] + 480

5   Vector                              0x0000000101217060 +[AvatarGenerator avatarForText:andColorIndex:] + 448

6   Vector                              0x0000000101217268 +[AvatarGenerator generateAvatarForMatrixItem:withDisplayName:] + 188

7   Vector                              0x000000010123c8d8 -[RoomBubbleCellData initWithEvent:andRoomState:andRoomDataSource:] + 348

8   Vector                              0x0000000101471548 __41-[MXKRoomDataSource processQueuedEvents:]_block_invoke + 2092

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001023591dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235919c _dispatch_client_callout + 16

11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102367dfc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 768

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235c6ac _dispatch_queue_invoke + 328

13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102368d54 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 352

14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236fe38 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 676

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478bb08 start_wqthread + 4

=================================================================

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setBackgroundColor:]

PID: 317, TID: 22759, Thread name: (none), Queue name: MXKRoomDataSource, QoS: 0

Backtrace:

4   Vector                              0x0000000101216a84 +[AvatarGenerator imageFromText:withBackgroundColor:] + 504

5   Vector                              0x0000000101217060 +[AvatarGenerator avatarForText:andColorIndex:] + 448

6   Vector                              0x0000000101217268 +[AvatarGenerator generateAvatarForMatrixItem:withDisplayName:] + 188

7   Vector                              0x000000010123c8d8 -[RoomBubbleCellData initWithEvent:andRoomState:andRoomDataSource:] + 348

8   Vector                              0x0000000101471548 __41-[MXKRoomDataSource processQueuedEvents:]_block_invoke + 2092

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001023591dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235919c _dispatch_client_callout + 16

11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102367dfc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 768

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235c6ac _dispatch_queue_invoke + 328

13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102368d54 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 352

14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236fe38 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 676

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478bb08 start_wqthread + 4

2018-09-11 11:31:04.088419+0530 Vector[317:22759] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setBackgroundColor:]

PID: 317, TID: 22759, Thread name: (none), Queue name: MXKRoomDataSource, QoS: 0

Backtrace:

4   Vector                              0x0000000101216a84 +[AvatarGenerator imageFromText:withBackgroundColor:] + 504

5   Vector                              0x0000000101217060 +[AvatarGenerator avatarForText:andColorIndex:] + 448

6   Vector                              0x0000000101217268 +[AvatarGenerator generateAvatarForMatrixItem:withDisplayName:] + 188

7   Vector                              0x000000010123c8d8 -[RoomBubbleCellData initWithEvent:andRoomState:andRoomDataSource:] + 348

8   Vector                              0x0000000101471548 __41-[MXKRoomDataSource processQueuedEvents:]_block_invoke + 2092

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001023591dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235919c _dispatch_client_callout + 16

11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102367dfc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 768

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010235c6ac _dispatch_queue_invoke + 328

13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102368d54 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 352

14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010236fe38 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 676

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018478bb08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Can anyone help me with this issue please???

This is the link where the demo of the issue which I mentioned about,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/za69zs5yzlpdvvb/Vector%20Chat.mov?dl=0

In edit screen enabled pause on issues.

[image]

I got the issue at this place what to do for this issue?

[image]

As per @holex said I have added dispatch queue

[image]

again in that line same error came so added dispatch queue for that line also but my app gets crashed. I have attached the log also.

```
2018-09-11 13:15:35.113653+0530 Vector[412:50340] [MXLogger] handleUncaughtException:
4744231993351678525 - 2018-09-11 07:45:35 +0000
*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: R0)
Application: Vector (com.agriya.devtest)
Application version: 0.2.3 (r0.2.3)
Matrix SDK version: 0.6.17
Build: (no build info)
iPhone 11.4.1

Main thread: YES
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184b66da4 <redacted> + 252
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000183d205ec objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184aff750 _CFArgv + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184a34c6c <redacted> + 948
    4   Vector                              0x0000000100b030a0 +[AvatarGenerator avatarForText:andColorIndex:] + 528
    5   Vector                              0x0000000100b03258 +[AvatarGenerator generateAvatarForMatrixItem:withDisplayName:] + 188
    6   Vector                              0x0000000100b2b4c4 -[MXRoom(Vector) setRoomAvatarImageIn:] + 1224
    7   Vector                              0x0000000100b14554 -[RecentTableViewCell render:] + 3168
    8   Vector                              0x0000000100d0da4c -[MXKInterleavedRecentsDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 440
    9   Vector                              0x0000000100b867f8 -[RecentsDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 2876
    10  UIKit                               0x000000018e8430cc <redacted> + 668
    11  UIKit                               0x000000018e842d84 <redacted> + 80
    12  UIKit                               0x000000018e841aa0 <redacted> + 2280
    13  UIKit                               0x000000018e83d5ec <redacted> + 140
    14  UIKit                               0x000000018e77a6f4 <redacted> + 1420
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000188cefe54 <redacted> + 184
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000188cf3fe4 <redacted> + 324
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000188c606c8 <redacted> + 320
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000188c881b0 <redacted> + 580
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000188c89030 <redacted> + 92
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184b0e910 <redacted> + 32
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184b0c238 <redacted> + 412
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184b0c884 <redacted> + 1436
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184a2cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000186a12020 GSEventRunModal + 100
    25  UIKit                               0x000000018ea4c758 UIApplicationMain + 236
    26  Vector                              0x0000000100b13508 main + 184
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001844bdfc0 <redacted> + 4
)
2018-09-11 13:15:35.144749+0530 Vector[412:50340] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: R0)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184b66d8c 0x183d205ec 0x184aff750 0x184a34c6c 0x100b030a0 0x100b03258 0x100b2b4c4 0x100b14554 0x100d0da4c 0x100b867f8 0x18e8430cc 0x18e842d84 0x18e841aa0 0x18e83d5ec 0x18e77a6f4 0x188cefe54 0x188cf3fe4 0x188c606c8 0x188c881b0 0x188c89030 0x184b0e910 0x184b0c238 0x184b0c884 0x184a2cda8 0x186a12020 0x18ea4c758 0x100b13508 0x1844bdfc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: quick hack: use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... })` in the method's body but that does not answer to your question _why_ that method is called on background thread, maybe there are some design-flows in your implementation what you need to resolve on a different way.

Comment: @holex actually its vector chat sdk I didn't make any changes in the source. It was the vector source downloaded from the git.

Comment: then you should report it as a bug to the author/dev directly.

Comment: @holex I made some changes check with that and let me know if you have any idea about it